# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot sign up a user that is already signing up

Tags: android, parse-platform, parseui

I use ParseUI to handle signup. I have a couple of users experiencing this crash when signing up for an account:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot sign up a user that is already signing up.
at com.parse.ParseUser.signUpAsync(ParseUser.java:694)
at com.parse.ParseUser.resolveLazinessAsync(ParseUser.java:1397)
at com.parse.ParseUser.saveAsync(ParseUser.java:502)
at com.parse.ParseUser.signUpAsync(ParseUser.java:716)
at com.parse.ParseUser.access$200(ParseUser.java:24)
at com.parse.ParseUser$3.then(ParseUser.java:656)
at com.parse.ParseUser$3.then(ParseUser.java:653)
at com.parse.TaskQueue.enqueue(TaskQueue.java:61)
at com.parse.ParseUser.signUpInBackground(ParseUser.java:653)
at com.parse.ParseUser.signUpInBackground(ParseUser.java:801)
at com.parse.ui.ParseSignupFragment.onClick(ParseSignupFragment.java:187)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4630)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19331)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

According to the users, it crashes right away when clicking the sign up button, instead of waiting for a few seconds of timeout. There is no duplicate account in the backend, they are signing up new.

One user has a custom ROM. Another user rooted his device before. But I am not sure that matters.

I cannot reproduce the problem. Most users do not experience this problem. I would appreciate your insights. Thanks.

Comment: Could it be that your click handler (ParseSignupFragment.java:187) is called twice?

Comment: Majority of the users have no problem signing up. Also, ParseSignupFragment is part of the ParseUI library which is used by many, so I would doubt it is called twice.